# In kafka 0.8 producer, we can't specify zk.connect without specifying broker.list

Tags: broker, producer, apache-kafka

I find that in Kafka 0.72, we can specify either zk.connect or broker.list. But in Kafka 0.8, we can only specify broker.list ,and we can’t specify zk.connect without specifying broker.list. I think, in this case, we can’t balance producer through zookeeper. If anyone use Kafka 0.8, or have some understanding with that?   Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can producer find the additions and removals of brokers in Kafka 0.8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313590/can-producer-find-the-additions-and-removals-of-brokers-in-kafka-0-8)

Answer (score 3):

You can still use a ZooKeeper client to retrieve the broker list:

```
ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient("localhost:2108", 4000, 6000, new BytesPushThroughSerializer());
List<String> brokerList = zkClient.getChildren("/brokers/ips");
```

According to that, you do not have to "hardcode" the broker list on client side and you are flexible as far as the system architecture is concerned. But anyway, this would add the ZooKeeper dependency again which is in fact an disadvantage for producer in several environments.

If you want to get a detailed view to the so called "cluster metadata API" solution, check out this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-369

Best

pre

Comment: This looks like it is no longer being registered in zookeeper in 0.8. It is now done by getting the json stored at /brokers/ids/*

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka 0.8, the producer is load balancing through the new cluster metadata API and the use of Zookeeper for that purpose has been removed.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But,if there are two partitions for topic1, one in kafka server1, another in kafka server2. Now, a producer which have a broker.list configuration with kafka server1. Will the producer store its message only in kafka server1 or in both kafka server 1 and kafka server 2?(We keep both kafka server1 and kafka server2 live).

Comment: Another question, you said ,the producer is load balancing through the new cluster metadata API. Could you tell me the exact API and whether it will balance load withoud manual configuration?